# получаем xhr через casper.js

Tags: javascript, парсер, phantomjs, xhr, casperjs

Когда я захожу в браузере по адресу `www.site.com` на вкладке network/xhr в хроме вижу ряд запросов. Как мне получить результат выполнения этих запросов с помощью casperjs? Я хочу чтобы мой скрипт сам заходил на сайт, дожидался их подрузки и забирал все полученные xhr. Это возможно?

Answer (score 2):

для начала надо включить сохранение контента

```
casper.on('page.initialized', function() {
  casper.page.captureContent = [/javascript/]
})
```

потом надо повесить функцию обработчкик по событию `resource.received`

```
casper.start();
casper.open(some_url);

casper.on('resource.received', function (resource) {
    var resourceUrl = resource.url, // ссылка по которой был загружен xhr
        resourceBody = resource.body // тело ресурса
    // дальше логика
})

casper.then(....) // логика обработки загрузки и тп

casper.run()
```